# cannot convert this case query from blob to text

Tags: mysql, blob

I would like to convert this blob query output to a text output, so i can use it directly on hibernate in a java datatable. can someone gently help me? I was trying with convert but probably I missed something.

```
select
    case
        when dp.idstatodocumentodipagamento = 4
            and
            (
                select
                    count(*)
                from
                    lineadocumentodipagamento lp
                where
                    dp.iddocumentodipagamento = iddocumentodipagamento
                    AND idstatodocumentodipagamento = 5
            ) > 0
            then concat
                (
                    'Linee imponibile ',
                    IFNULL
                    (
                        (
                            select
                                count(*)
                            from
                                lineadocumentodipagamento lp
                            where
                                idstatodocumentodipagamento = 5
                                and lp.idcontocorrente <> 64
                        ),
                        ''
                    ),
                    '/',
                    IFNULL(
                        (
                            select
                                count(*)
                            from
                                lineadocumentodipagamento lp
                            where
                                idcontocorrente <> 64
                        ), ''),
                    ' ; ',
                    'Linee IVA ',
                    IFNULL
                    (
                        (
                            SELECT
                                COUNT(*)
                            FROM
                                lineadocumentodipagamento lp
                            WHERE
                                idstatodocumentodipagamento = 5
                                AND lp.idcontocorrente = 64
                        ),
                        ''
                    ),
                    '/',
                    IFNULL(
                        (
                            SELECT
                                COUNT(*)
                            FROM
                                lineadocumentodipagamento lp
                            WHERE
                                lp.idcontocorrente = 64
                        ), '')
                )
    END as z
from
    documentodipagamento dp,
    lineadocumentodipagamento ldp
where
    dp.iddocumentodipagamento = ldp.iddocumentodipagamento
```

Comment: Format your code please, its difficult to read.

Comment: I made a crack at indenting this to make it easier to follow.

Comment: thank you for indenting and cracking

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding

```
convert (count(*) using utf8)
```

to every select